# gradle - listing multiple subprojects for 'project'

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Is there a way to list multiple projects for a common dependency. I tried as follows, it doesn't work. I don't want to list individually for a better maintenance.

```
project(':com.example.bundle1', ':com.example.bundle2') {
    dependencies {
      compile project(':com.example.common')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can leverage groovy list support here:

```
[':com.example.bundle1', ':com.example.bundle2'].each {
   project(it) {
     dependencies {
         compile project(':com.example.common')
     }
   }
}
```